# webview detuct html tag how android

Tags: android, html, webview, tags

```
articleText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();

                   Logger.logInfo(tag, "getExtra = "+ hr.getExtra() + "\t\t Type=" + hr.getType());
```

// i build html file with video url, how can i get the video type and url in webview?

//still i am struggling how can i get video type and url........pls help

Comment: Please clearly state your question. It's hard to tell what is being asked here

Comment: i need when i click webview i need the which type of html are there

Answer (score 1):

you can dectect HTML TAG inside WebView onTouch as:

```
articleText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();


Logger.logInfo(tag, "getExtra = "+ hr.getExtra() + 
          "\t\t Type=" + hr.getType());

int resultType = result.getType();

switch (resultType){  
  case HitTestResult.ANCHOR_TYPE:
    Log.v("HitTestResult.ANCHOR_TYPE");
  break;
  case HitTestResult.IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE:
    Log.v("HitTestResult.IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE");
  break;
  case HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE:
    Log.v("HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE");
  break;
  case HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE:
    Log.v("HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE");
  break;
  default:
    Log.v("Invalid");

  }
}
```

Comment: @user1427548 : you can see here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.HitTestResult.html#getType%28%29 for available contains

Comment: @user1427548 : and try `Log.v("result.getType() ::"+result.getType())`

Comment: @user1427548 : i don't what i known i told you already add also give a reference which tags you can find easy . but if you have any hack or trick to do this then you can share it as answer

Comment: sorry i cant get video type and url