# detect text box click in a webview to pop up the keyboard

Tags: android, webview

how do I detect textbox click in webview? I want to pop-up the keyboard when user clicks on a textbox in a webview. I have my keyboard defined in code upon calling displayKeyboard() in my code will display it but how do i trigger that call?

Comment: By 'textbox' do you mean an input text field in the html page ? If so, then it should be automatically done by the webview.

Comment: @PhilippeA please read the question carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Button yourButton = new Button(context);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(this);

webView.addJavascriptInterface(yourButton,"injectedObject");

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //displayKeyboard() 
}
```

The HTML button will be as:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="some_id" onclick="yourButton.performClick();" />
```

You can also read about it [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.HitTestResult.html)

As you don't have any control on the webpage, you might want to read this:

[HitTestResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.HitTestResult.html)

and

[webview detuct html tag how android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757547/webview-detuct-html-tag-how-android)

And notice that you probably need to dearch for this:

```
     int type = result.getType();

     if (type == WebView.HitTestResult.EDIT_TEXT_TYPE) {
         return;
     }
```

Comment: I dont have any button. Its a textbox inside any site, like search box in website.

Comment: That means you don't have any control on the HTML? it could be just a random site?

Comment: Yes. user gives input and that site is random.

Comment: it always returns edit text type in my case, even if i touch rest of the part of webview.